# Java data structures for indexing objects

Tags: java, data-structures

I am building a system where you can define a schema for a complex object and store and retrieve the objects and schema's via an api.

I would like to be able to index the items in my collection.

For my equals index I was imagining I could use HashMap's

```
new HashMap<UUID, HashMap<UUID, HashMap<String, ArrayList<UUID>>>()
```

Which would be mapped as below

```
ObjectTypeUuid
-> FieldTypeUuid
-> FieldValue
-> ArrayList of ObjectUuid
```

I am not sure this would work too well for doing greater than and less than operations.

What other data structures could help me achieve my goals?

Comment: Your problem is not clear to me.  What are you trying to store and how do you need to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the HashMap with a TreeMap and you can achieve greater than or lesser than queries. However you will have to choose your keys carefully as the queries will operate on your keys.

In TreeMap, in order to get all entries greater than a key : map.tailMap(key)
 and vice-versa for all entries smaller than a key: map.headMap(key)

Comment: Thanks for that, I am a php engineer, so not very clued up on java data types but this seems like an excellent choice. I will try this out and see what results I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to what Kiran K wrote, I would think about using proxy objects that contain your schema definitions.
These objects can contain recursive/circular object-references, that look like:

```
public class ObjectType {
   // UUID -> Value
   public HashMap<String, ObjectType> content;
}
```

This enables you to model schemata as complex as you like. 
In addition you could also model functions as a part of objects if you add another class FunctionType that extends Object.

Many Greetings
biro